# Generate html list from query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

this is my first post, my problem is that i'm getting problems when i try to generate a *select* in html using a php mysqli query, the problem is basically that i don't get any result.

My html is looks like that:

```
<select name="sede">
   <option value="" selected=""> -- Select -- </option>
       <?php 
          include ("conexion_BBDD.php");

          $sql = "SELECT nombre FROM sedes";
          $result = mysqli_query($conexion_bbdd, $sql);

          while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array($result) ) { ?>
             <option value=" <?php echo $row['nombre']; ?> " >
             <?php echo $row['nombre']; ?>
             </option>
         <?php } ?>
</select>
```

So can anyone help me with that?

Comment: You're using `mysql_fetch_array()` instead of `mysqli_fetch_array()` .

Comment: Damn... Didn't see. Sorry and thanks, now it works well. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### You can try this

### you can change this line to

```
 while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array($result) ) { ?>
```

### This

```
while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) ) { ?>
```